# where should I create a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I am learning to use pthreads but I am not sure where to define and execute a pthread. I must have an .h file and my function is in .c file. Where does the pthread go in the h or c file?

Comment: Implementations of functions go into a `.c` file. This is the same for functions used as a thread function.

Comment: A tutorial is here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical obstacle to create thread in some function in header. If you however include this header from different files you will get multiple definitions compile error because after preprocessing compiler will be presented with repeated definitions of same function. This will brake *one definition rule*. You should write only declaration of function in header and provide an implementation in source file.